# SVN how to set a FSFS repository to be read only?

Tags: svn, fsfs

I have a couple of FSFS based file system SVN repositories that I wish to switch to be read only. Is there a flag I can enable that will stop svn clients from writing to the repository?

Alternatively I could simply remove all write permissions from the folder, but that feels overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`svnadmin freeze`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.freeze.html) to make your repos read-only or configure user or filesystem permissions so that noone could commit. Proper approach depends on the actual task you have but I guess that `svnadmin freeze` should help you in most cases.

`svnadmin freeze` is available starting with Subversion 1.8. Make sure that your Subversion is up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [start-commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.start-commit.html) hook with content like this:

```
echo "Repository is readonly"
exit 1
```

Comment: @NeilP Repository hooks behavior doesn't depend on repository type. What OS do you use?

Comment: I'm on windows, it's one of those nasty fsfs repos on a network share (hence why I want to kill it!)

Comment: @NeilP Make sure that you created batch file for the hook. I.e. ``repos\hooks\start-commit.bat``

Comment: @NeilP Great! Btw ``svnadmin freeze`` may not work correctly if repository on NFS share and users are accessing it directly. So start-commit hook solution may be better in your case.

Comment: That's what I had found, it looks like the correct way of doing this, but maybe not in my case.

Comment: @NeilP ``svnadmin freeze`` is designed for backups, not for locking repository. The ``svnadmin freeze`` command obtains temporary lock and will be released once ``svnadmin freeze`` command finished.